# use sed to replace "file={{bla-bla}}" with "file={bla-bla}"

Tags: regex, sed

my bibtex file is corrupted in a sense that I need to change
`file = {{name:/path/to/file.pdf:application/pdf}},`
with `file = {name:/path/to/file.pdf:application/pdf},` that is, remove the first pair of curly brackets. 
All the strings I am interested start with `file = {{`.

My first attempt is
`echo "file = {{name:/path/to/file.pdf:application/pdf}}," | sed 's/file = {{/file = {/g;s/}}/}/g'`

The problem with this one is that it also alters lines like
`title = {{ blablabla }}` which i don't it want to.

How does one write a REGEX with something like `s/file = {{EVERYTHING-IN-BETWEEN/file = {KEEP-WHAT-WAS-THERE}/g` ?

p.s. if it's not possible with `sed`, any other unix commands are welcome.

p.p.s. I am on OS-X, sed here is apparently different to GNU, so some answers below do not work for me, unfortunately.

Comment: Is the `file = {{ ... }}` contents always on exactly one line?

Comment: yes, it is always one line. No line breaks (Unix/Windows) between `{{` and `}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
sed 's/\(file = \){\({[^}]*}\)}/\1\2/g'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is probably wrong for your situation, but this will change any double brace to a single brace:

```
sed  's/\([{}]\)\1/\1/g' <<END
{{
}}
file={{bar-blah}}
{}
}{
END
```

```
{
}
file={bar-blah}
{}
}{
```

The search part `\([{}]\)\1` finds a single open or close brace followed by what was just captured. The replacement part is the single captured character.

Comment: correct, i need to preserve some of the other pairs `{{` and `}}`.

Comment: This is still a useful matching feature and could be used with proper matching-line limiting to avoid needing two `s///` commands.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both opening and closing braces are on the same line and no *other* pairs of braces exist on that same line then this should do what you want:

```
sed '/file *= *{{/{s/{{/{/; s/}}/}/}' file
```

That's:

- `/file = {{/` - match lines that have `file = {{` on it
- `{` - start a group of commands
- `s/{{/{/` - replace `{{` with `{` once
- `s/}}/}/` - replace `}}` with `}` once
- `}` - end a group of commands

If OS X sed cannot handle that command, and this version without the command grouping does not work either:

```
sed '/file *= *{{/s/}}/}/; /file *= *{{/s/{{/{/'
```

then this, hopefully, should:

```
sed -e '/file *= *{{/s/}}/}/' -e '/file *= *{{/s/{{/{/'
```

or, to steal from [glenn jackman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30811427/258523) a bit:

```
sed -e '/file *= *{{/s/\([{}]\)\1/\1/g'
```

Comment: does not work for me `sed: 1: "/file = {{/{s/{{/{/; s/ ...": bad flag in substitute command: '}'`

Comment: @Denis You copied and pasted exactly? What version of sed?

Comment: `sed '/file = {{/{s/{{/{/; s/}}/}/}'` still no luck. Nevermind, OS-X is stupid sometimes... p.s. thanks for explanations!

Comment: `sed: 1: "/file *= *{{/{s/{{/{/;  ...": bad flag in substitute command: '}'`

Comment: The `*` was to handle more than one space.

Comment: for OSX -e option instead ; which is gnu favor

Comment: @EdMorton Bah! Probably should have known better for a sed question. =)

Answer (score 0):

huh, GNU sed

```
echo "file={{bla-bla}}" | sed 's/\(file\s*=\s*\){\s*{\s*\([^}]*\)}\s*}\s*/\1{\2}/'
```

file={bla-bla}
\s is catching eventual white space characters

assuming that '}' is not inside internal string

Comment: it will work if instead \s u use simple space or [[:space:]] (if other whitespace characters other than space are there)